# error: 'else' without 'if' in CodinGame

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;

class Player {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // game loop
    while (true) {
        String enemy1 = in.next(); // name of enemy 1
        int dist1 = in.nextInt(); // distance to enemy 1
        String enemy2 = in.next(); // name of enemy 2
        int dist2 = in.nextInt(); // distance to enemy 2

        // Write an action using System.out.println()
        // To debug: System.err.println("Debug messages...");

        if (dist1 < dist2) {
            System.out.println(ememy1);
        else {
            System.out.println(enemy2);
            break;
        }
        }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm working on this challenge in CodinGame, but I'm stuck on the error. I'm not sure if I should be using else if, or whatever else? This is the error that I am getting:

```
Standard Error Stream:
error: 'else' without 'if'
        else {`
        ^
```

Comment: Check your brackets. Indent your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a bracket AFTER the `System.out.println(enemy1)` line and get rid of one of them after the `else` statement. They are separate expressions: IF this is true, do something. ELSE, do something else.

Answer (score -1):

Extra and wrongly placed braces:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;

class Player {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        // game loop
        while (true) {
            String enemy1 = in.next(); // name of enemy 1
            int dist1 = in.nextInt(); // distance to enemy 1
            String enemy2 = in.next(); // name of enemy 2
            int dist2 = in.nextInt(); // distance to enemy 2

            // Write an action using System.out.println()
            // To debug: System.err.println("Debug messages...");

            if (dist1 < dist2) {
                System.out.println(ememy1);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(enemy2);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, indent your code properly so that you can see there the blocks end.

Comment: You should remove the `break`.

Comment: @Maxime the error message wouldn't be caused by the `break`.

Comment: The break doesn't cause an error message, but it won't pass all the test cases. You mustn't break.